# Parallel File Processing: What are recommended ways?

Tags: java, file-io, parallel-processing, akka, typesafe

This is by large combination of design and code problem.

**Use Case**
- Given many log files in range (2MB - 2GB), I need to parse each of these logs and apply some processing, generate Java `POJO`.
- For this problem, lets assume that we have just `1` log file
- Also, the idea is to making best use of System. Multiple cores are available.

**Alternative 1**
- Open file (synchronous), read each line, generate `POJO`s

```
FileActor -> read each line -> List<POJO>
```

***Pros***: simple to understand
***Cons***: Serial Process, not taking advantage of multiple cores in the system

**Alternative 2**
- Open File (synchronous), read `N` lines (`N` is configurable), pass on to different actors to process

```
                                                    / LogLineProcessActor 1
FileActor -> LogLineProcessRouter (with 10 Actors) -- LogLineProcessActor 2
                                                    \ LogLineProcessActor 10
```

***Pros*** Some parallelization, by using different actors to process part of lines. Actors will make use of available cores in the system (? how, may be?)
***Cons*** Still Serial, because file read in serial fashion

**Questions**
- is any of the above choice a good choice?
- Are there better alternatives?

Please provide valuable thoughts here

Thanks a lot

Comment: I think [ParallelStreams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) might be suitable for your problem.

Comment: Or even https://storm.apache.org/ if you're continually getting new files and want a really robust pipeline.

Comment: This solution needs to be installed on customer machines so I am not sure if `Storm` is feasible.

Comment: If it's a log file to analyze you may probably also make use of [logstash](http://logstash.net/)

Answer (score 2):

Why not take advantage of what's already available, and use the paralell stream stuff, that comes with jdk 1.8? I would start with something like this, and see how it performs:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get( /* path to a log file */ ))
     .parallel() // make the stream work paralell
     .map(YourBean::new) // Or some mapping method to your bean class
     .forEach(/* process here the beans*/);
```

You may need some tweaks with the thread pooling, because `paralell()` by default is executed using `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`, and you can't really customize it to achieve maximum performance, but people seem to find workarounds for that too, [some stuff about the topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163108/custom-thread-pool-in-java-8-parallel-stream).

Answer (score 0):

The alternative 2 looks good. I would just change a thing. Read the biggest chunk of file you can. IO will be a problem if you do it in small bursts.
As there are several files, I would create an actor to get the name of the files, reading a particular folder. Then it will send the path to each file to the `LogLineReader`. It will read a big chunk of the file. And finally it  will send each line to the `LogLineProcessActor`.
Be aware that they may process the lines out of order. If that is not a problem, they will keep your CPU busy.

If you feel adventurous, you could also try the new [akka stream 1.0](http://letitcrash.com/post/117271329227/akka-streams-http-1-0-rc1-announcement).