# How to search user in multiple LDAP active directory domain parallel in Java?

Tags: multithreading, active-directory, ldap, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

If I have multiple domains, and when I am not sure in which domain user will be exists then want to search that user in all domains to fetch its details like first name and last name.

I have around 10 different domain and each has different provider URL and service account to connect. 
Looking for sample java code to fetch the user details faster from across all the domains may be doing some parallel search? (using multi-threading or observer pattern based program) .

Comment: You could take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25800299/1202807

Comment: Are they in the same AD Forrest? (also Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No they are not in same AD forrest.