# Promises for Android?

Tags: android, promise

How do you face nested callbacks in Android? For example, in my app, I use Locations API and then, when I have the current lat-lng, I do an HTTP request to my server. In this situation, I have two nested callbacks. It's not so bad, but what if I had three or more? I've read about it [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10695152/434171), but I wonder if there are something like Promises for Android.

All I've found is [this](https://github.com/CodeAndMagic/android-deferred-object). Someone knows more about the subject?

Comment: Sure https://github.com/jdeferred/jdeferred , but take note that without Java 8 functional interface syntax, this looks really really ugly. Promises being a concept taken from functional programming that is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is something pretty similar already available as part of the Java language, and supported by Android: [java.util.concurrent.Future](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). Perhaps it is good enough for your needs.

By the way, Java 8, *which Android does not yet support*, has a variant called [CompletableFuture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) that is even closer to a Promise.

Comment: Thanks. Now, this is used in real development? I've seen the source code for iosched and others Android apps but I've never heard of Promises.

Comment: Yes, Future is used quite a bit. Here is a tutrial that might be helpful: http://java.dzone.com/articles/javautilconcurrentfuture

Comment: [CompletableFuture](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) was added in Android 7 (API level 24)

Comment: Java 8 is partially supported (not Jack) https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html

Comment: "There is something pretty similar already available as part of the Java language, and supported by Android: java.util.concurrent.Future.") Futures really aren't too similar to Promises. While Promises are callback-based, Futures are usually waitet for synchronously.

Comment: Remember you can use the backported `CompletableFuture` that's made specifically for Android if you want to support older devices. Check out: https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrofuture

Answer (score 7):

As of 2020, android has support for CompletableFuture, Java's answer to Javascript promises:
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture

If that is not possible for your app's android api level, then see https://github.com/retrostreams/android-retrofuture .

Example:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
            String result = somebackgroundFunction();
            return result;
        }).thenAcceptAsync(theResult->{
            //process the result
        }).exceptionallyCompose(error->{
            ///process the error
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(error);
        });
```

To handle the result and update the UI, you need to specify main thread executor:

```
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->{
            String result = somebackgroundFunction();
            return result;
        }).thenAcceptAsync(theResult->{
            //process the result
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
                .exceptionallyComposeAsync(error->{
            ///process the error
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(error);
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context));
```

Answer (score 5):

This very old post, but, I want to share my problem and solution here.

I has similar problem, I need to perform 4 network task one after another while login to my app and finally when all requests are success opening the landing screen of the app. Initially I used nested callback, but now i found a new android-Promise library https://github.com/crawlinknetworks/android-promise it solved my problem. It is very easy and simple to use.

#### Following: How it is working?

```
doSomeTask(int someValue, String extra)
    .then(res -> doSecondTask((MyObject) res))       // res is result form doSomeTask()
    .then(res -> doThirdTask((OtherObject) res)))    // res is result form doThirdTask()
    .then(res -> doFourthTask((int) res)))           // res is result form doThirdTask()
    .then(res -> doFivthTask())
    .then(res -> {
     // Consume result of the previous function
     return true;    // done
    })
    .error(err -> handleError());                       // Incase of any p.reject()
                            // all from above function error will be available here
```

Comment: Excelent! like a JS!

Comment: It appears from github that you may actually be the original author of this work. As noted by someone else in the "issues" page, the licence was changed from Apache to a more restrictive one in the 2nd commit (which also fixed/added a bunch of things). Was the restricted licence a mistake, or is it no longer available for free use?