# How do wait for a service to start on Android without using bindService

Tags: java, android

I know that I can wait for a service start by doing

```
bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

where `serviceConnection` implements a callback that is called when the service starts. However, I need a service that is less killeable, that is, a service hat uses `startForeground`. But this can only work if I start my service with `startService`, which does not provide a way to pass a `serviceConnection`.

How can I wait for an android service to start?

Why I need it to start? Well, because I need to call things inside it by doing `service.method1();` etc.

Comment: Hi, aren't promises an option to solve this? have the original method to return a promise and just wait for it to complete or be rejected

Comment: "How can I wait for an android service to start?" -- you can't. :Well, because I need to call things inside it by doing service.method1();" -- that may not be necessary, and I would focus your efforts on trying to remove this requirement.

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego you mean wait in a loop? Could work, but how are services able to return promises?

Comment: @CamiloCasadiego: The Android SDK does not have a `Promise` class. And, while I think people have ported the JavaScript `Promise` concept to Java, that would not help here.

Comment: If all you are looking to do is to keep using `bindService()` while having that service be a foreground service, [Carles' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62163347/115145) should work. I still suggest that you revisit your overall approach to services, though.

Comment: @CommonsWare  my mistake, I thought promises were also part of android but here you can find a way to handle this on android, I think the problem they solve is very similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23164196/promises-for-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use both methods, first start the service with startForeground() and then use bindService() to wait for the service connection.

The service starts in the foreground and you can use the service methods.

Starting Service:

```
listenServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListenService.class);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

    //Start in Foreground
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, listenServiceIntent);

    if (connection != null) {
        //Then bind service
        bindService(listenServiceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
else {
    startService(listenServiceIntent);
    if (connection != null) {
        bindService(listenServiceIntent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

Waiting Connection:

```
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onServiceConnected");

            ListenService.LocalBinder binder = (ListenService.LocalBinder) service;
            listenService = binder.getService();

            //HERE you can use service methods

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected");
        }
};
```

Create notificationChannel:

```
public static void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL,
                    NOTIFICATION_NAME,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );

            NotificationManager manager =    context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
            }
        }
    }
```

Push notification:

```
public static Notification pushNotification(Context context, String notificationText, Class classNotification) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, classNotification);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);


        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
                .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.notification_title))
                .setContentText(notificationText)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosinfondo_mini)
                .setColor(Color.MAGENTA)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();
    }
```

In onCreate() inside your Service:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Lib.createNotificationChannel(this);
        startForeground(1, Lib.pushNotification(this, "Started", ListenActivity.class));
    }
```

Comment: should I put the `startForeground` command on the service as well? `startService` and `bindService` call different things starts in the service.

Comment: Also I see that you call `startForegroundService`, but as I recall, truly foreground services require a notification to indicate the app is on background.

Comment: I show a notification when the service starts. inside onCreate() startForeground(1, Lib.pushNotification(this, "Starting...", ListenActivity.class));

Comment: `Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CHANNEL_ID")
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .build();
        startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID,notification);`

Comment: I did this but I see no notification. This is inside the `onCreate` of the service. I also printed something before it just to show it was running  `onCreate`. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I edit my response, including my methods to show notifications, regards

Comment: Sorry for taking too much time to accept. Excelent answer!